# How I can change the Electron app icon without electron-packager?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to change default electron icon without `electron-packager`?

Many sites describe the way that using `electron-packager`.
But I don't want to use electron-packager to learn feature of electron.

How I can do it?

My platform is darwin. (OS X 10.10.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a platform, but for OS X (darwin) you just need to replace the `name_here.icns` file at the path `<approot>/Contents/Resources/name_here.icns` with your own `.icns` file and when you reload the app it will have a then new icon.

That being said, Electron packager is cool because it be platform agnostic and it can automate this.